# Export and Import Custom Views on Tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau server where there are several 'sites' configured.
There is a workbook X in 'siteA' which i want to copy to another site 'siteB'.

Now there are several custom views (mostly with different filter values) created over sheets/dashboards from workbook X. All these custom views were created by me , I have full admin role on both 'siteA' and 'siteB' (actually on the whole server). All the custom views are marked 'public'.

Normally, I would just download the workbook X from 'siteA' and republish it to 'siteB'. However I want to be able to see/use all the custom views in 'siteB' without having to manually create them all over again.

Is there a way to to this?
I couldn't find any such 'official' solution anywhere.  I am fine with trying hacky, one off solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there is not a way to do this workbook by workbook. The closest I know of at present (up through 10.5) is to export the entire site and then import the entire site, which will preserve the custom views. And that's not very close to what you're looking for.

If you search [Tableau's Ideas forum](https://community.tableau.com/community/ideas) for "custom views" you'll find several feature requests. [This one in particular](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/6127) seems relevant - I'd vote for it! [This one](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/6550) also seems related.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that but you can export the view as they are stored in postgres workgroup database in repository_data in XML format. That way at least you can see what was contained in the view (filters, parameters, etc.)

Example of export (first you have to trace the ID of the custom view):

```
SELECT lo_export(repository_data.content, '/home/ubuntu/view.twb') 
FROM repository_data 
WHERE repository_data.id = (select id from repository_data 
where tracking_id = (select data_id from customized_views where id = 100));
```